# How to navigate on Here Android SDK with a route calculated from the fleet API?

Tags: android, here-api

I need to use overlays proposed by the Here fleet API when calculating my route. I use the premium Android SDK.

I have successfully calculated it with the request fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json from which I receive a json description of the itinerary.

How can I use this json to display it easily on my map and make a turn by turn navigation ? Both of them need a "Route" object but it is only created by the internal "routeCore" but I don't find any way to create it from a json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to use the FleetAPI json response for navigation in the Premium Android SDK. This might change in future versions, but at the moment only showing the json response as MapPolyline (route) on the map canvas would work.

Comment: That's what I was afraid off. Thank you

Comment: @Marco Is this feature available now? Any idea?